# Duration with days and hours and mins in presto sql

Tags: sql, tableau-api, presto

I tried one query to get duration with days and duration in hrs and mins , need to create new column for duration days and duration time in presto sql,but I only got hours and days not with mins. I need hours and mins in the same column after differentiating them.

```
From_unixtime(start_date) as start_date, 
From_unixtime(target_date) as target_date,
Date_diff('hour',start_date, targets_date) as duration_time,
Date_diff('day',start_date, targets_date) as duration_day,
```

Comment: Can you please share some sample data and desired output?